how to show the transaction history of ton web
I make a request as in the manual and everything goes fine
const walletContract = client.open(wallet);
const seqno = await walletContract.getSeqno();
console.log(seqno);

await walletContract.sendTransfer({
  secretKey: key.secretKey,
  seqno: seqno,
  messages: [
    internal({
      to: "EQA4V9tF4lY2S_J-sEQR7aUj9IwW-Ou2vJQlCn--2DLOLR5e",
      value: "0.09", // 0.05 TON
      body: "Hello", // optional comment
      bounce: false,
    }),
  ],
});

let currentSeqno = seqno;
while (currentSeqno == seqno) {
  console.log("waiting for transaction to confirm...");
  await sleep(1500);
  currentSeqno = await walletContract.getSeqno();
}
console.log("transaction confirmed!");

and now I have a question, how can I view the transaction history? Are there any methods for this?

https://docs.tonconsole.com/tonapi/api-v2
You can find everything at here.
The tonconsole api is the best one to track apis.
Just one tx hash of the whole transaction

You can use Toncenter API to look for transactions of an account, the method for this purpose is transactions accessible from /api/vs/transactions.
